# Generic perform Request, using Generics

Tags: swift, generics

I would like to make a perform request function in swift using Generics.  I want to make the call and switch on my enum Result based on what I get back.  However, I don't understand the : 'cannot invoke performRequest with an argument list of type (NSURLRequest, (Result<__>) -> ())'  Why can't I have an unnamed parameter here?  I have also tried something like the following : r<*MyStruct*> --- but I then get an expected expression error.  Any help explaining the above Result<_> error would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
enum Result<A> {
    case Value
    case Error
}

func performRequest<A>(request:NSURLRequest, callback:(Result<A>) -> ()) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    callback(parseResponse(data, response: response, error: error))
    }
    task.resume()
}

class SampleClass {

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!)

init() {
    performRequest(request) { r in -------- errors out
        switch r {
          case .Value:

          case .Error:
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the signature of `parseResponse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `performRequest`, you have not given the compiler enough information about the generic parameter you intend to use. The critical part that is missing is that `parseResponse` needs to return a `Result` that is parameterised in the same way as the callback. However, in the snippet you provided, `parseResponse` is not generic.

I believe this will do what you intend. In this scenario, I've parameterised the `Result` with `String`, but you can substitute any other type.

```
// multi-purpose (generic) Result type
enum Result<A>
{
    case Value(A) // because you parameterised the enum, you might as well take advantage of the type
    case Error
}

// this is a custom parser, you may substitute your own that returns a different type
func parseString( data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError? ) -> Result<String> {
    if let _ = error {
        return Result.Error
    }
    return Result.Value("Success")
}

// this function is completely generic, but the parser and callback need to be compatible
func performRequest<A>( request:NSURLRequest,
                         parser:( NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError? ) -> Result<A>,
                       callback:( Result<A> ) -> Void ) {
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        ( data, response, error ) -> Void in
        callback( parser( data, response, error ) )
    }
    task.resume()
}

let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!)

// actual invocation, now I need to pass in a concrete parser and callback with a specific type
performRequest( request, parser: parseString ) { // parseString returns a Result<String>
    r in
    switch r {
    case .Value( let value ):
        // because I passed in a parser that returns a Result<String>, I know that "value" is a String here
        print( "Succeeded with value: \(value)" )
        break;
    case .Error:
        print( "an error occurred" )
        break;
    }
}
```